# How to achieve this element layout within a bootstrap well

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get the components to layout like they are in this picture. I'm using a bootstrap well and I've already written the button styles. I've messed around with display:inline-block and floats but I've yet to get the appropriate alignment of components.
[image]

the markup I have used is as follows.

```
<section class="row">
        <article class="span12">
            <article class="well">
                <h3>Interested in working with us?</h3>
                <p>We are currently accepting projects for Fall 2013.</p>
                <a class="btn hero-btn" href="#">Get In Touch</a>
            </article>
        </article>      
</section>
```

Comment: .hero-btn is simply the styles for the button, and it only modifies the colors to make the button flat so disregard that

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g5GLR/

I've gotten close but as you can see it's horrific on resize as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you change the HTML so that the button comes first, above the H3? Then it would be easy, using a single `float`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g5GLR/1/

Comment: Thanks thats an improvement but there's still a vertical alignment disparity and the text should be split into multiple lines instead of piled together on a single line.

Comment: the behaviour of the h3 and the span can be corrected by setting their display both to block. http://jsfiddle.net/g5GLR/3/ Not sure what to do about the vertical position of the button though.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit and got it working using your last fiddle, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the elements in html should work -

```
<article class="well heroWell">
                    <h3 class="heroh4 inline">Interested in working with us?</h3>
             <a class="btn hero-btn inline" href="#">Get In Touch</a>   
    <span class="heroSpan inline">We are currently accepting projects for Fall 2013.</span>


            </article>
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/g5GLR/2/

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the same issues apply as in Mr Lister's solution, there's still a vertical alignment issue and the text is still on the same line as opposed to being split onto single lines. Applying line breaks makes the whole thing go back to being skewed